# Select box html horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, webforms, scrollbar

I want use select box and when overflow then show scroll in select box

**css**

```
#selectbox{
 width:100%;
 overflow: scroll;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="width:140px;">
    <select name="selectbox" size="5"  id="selectbox">
        <option value="1">one two three four five six</option>
        <option value="2">seven eight</option>
        <option value="3">nine ten</option>
        <option value="1">one two three four five six</option>
        <option value="2">seven eight</option>
        <option value="3">nine ten</option>
        <option value="1">one two three four five six</option>
        <option value="2">seven eight</option>
        <option value="3">nine ten</option>
        <option value="1">one two three four five six</option>
        <option value="2">seven eight</option>
        <option value="3">nine ten</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

but show just vertical scroll.How can solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

To see these changes quickly:see [here](http://screencast.com/t/1dATUXDU7KBB)

These are the changes:

1. First see that I've changed the css from selectbox to that of div.This is because we want to allow scrolling on our div rather than in the selectboxes.
2. Use

   ```
   overflow-x:auto;
   overflow-y:auto;
   ```
3. Setting width for div to see the scrolling at work.
4. Removed width here, as it conflicts previous definition.

To see working demo: see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UnkEG/17/)

Comment: Just `overflow-y:auto;` is sufficient, I think

Comment: On my browser, the last jsfiddle doesn't show the vertical scrollbar until you scroll al the way to the right.

Comment: I only added `overflow-x: auto;` to the `select` element and it worked in Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

All other answers what i searched cant fully hide embedded vertical scrollbar when you try these div tricks (and you got weird double vertical scrollers), at least in Firefox. So i made one, which works, you can have vertical and horizontad scrollbars but i tested only in FF. another issue is what when you move selection by pressing up & down keys and it goes beyond visible area it didnt scroll automatically, so you need to provide your additional JS code to handle that.

```css
.block1 {
  max-width: 100px; 
  max-height: 100px; 
  overflow:auto;
  display: block;
}

.block2 {
  display: inline-block; 
  vertical-align: top; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  border-right: 1px solid #a4a4a4;
}
```

```html
<div class="block1">
    <div class="block2">
      <select multiple style="margin-right:-17px" size="11">
        <option>123</option>
        <option>1234</option>
        <option>12345</option>
        <option>123456</option>
        <option selected>12345777777777777777777777777777</option>
        <option>123458</option>
        <option>123459</option>
        <option>12345</option>
        <option>1234</option>
        <option>123</option>
        <option>12</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful info. You can remove `block2` entirely here though.

Comment: So one key here is that you set the `size` property. Without this, the vertical scrollbar gets added onto the `<select multiple>` instead of the outer `div`, and then it's not visible when not scrolled all the way to the right. (Not too difficult to update this with JS though.)

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot to come up with my own: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66328940/1599699

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [coolcoder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41088768/1599699), I've found probably the best solution we'll be able to get:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#outerDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
}

#innerDiv {
  display: grid;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#multiSelect {
  width: max-content;
  min-width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerDiv">
  <div id="innerDiv">
    <select id="multiSelect" multiple>
      <option>123</option>
      <option>1234</option>
      <option>12345</option>
      <option>123456</option>
      <option selected>123457777777777777777777777777771234577777777777777777777777777712345777777777777777777777777777123457777777777777777777777777771234577777777777777777777777777712345777777777777777777777777777</option>
      <option>123458</option>
      <option>123459</option>
      <option>12345</option>
      <option>1234</option>
      <option>123</option>
      <option>12</option>
      <option>123458</option>
      <option>123459</option>
      <option>12345</option>
      <option>1234</option>
      <option>123</option>
      <option>12</option>
      <option>123458</option>
      <option>123459</option>
      <option>12345</option>
      <option>1234</option>
      <option>123</option>
      <option>12</option>
      <option>123458</option>
      <option>123459</option>
      <option>12345</option>
      <option>1234</option>
      <option>123</option>
      <option>12</option>
      <option>123458</option>
      <option>123459</option>
      <option>12345</option>
      <option>1234</option>
      <option>123</option>
      <option>12</option>
      <option>123458</option>
      <option>123459</option>
      <option>12345</option>
      <option>1234</option>
      <option>123</option>
      <option>12</option>
      <option>123458</option>
      <option>123459</option>
      <option>12345</option>
      <option>1234</option>
      <option>123</option>
      <option>12</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/65kahu4s)

Several notes:

1. It does require an inner and an outer `div` both; I wasn't able to get this to work so well any other way.
2. When **both** scrollbars show up, you have to scroll the horizontal scrollbar all the way right in order to see the vertical scrollbar (though vertical mouse scrolling still works). This appears to be utterly unavoidable...
3. On the plus side, this is totally dynamic/flexible. You'll note that I'm not setting any manual `size`, `width`, `height`, etc.
4. I used `display: grid;`'s here, but `flex` might work as well, not sure. I only used `grid`'s because MDN said they worked 2 dimensionally whereas `flex`'s were 1 dimensional.
5. It seems that the container of all of the above may matter as well. It works for me to put it all in a `<div>` with `display: flex; flex-direction: 2;` styling.

Comment: Innovative solution, that doesn't change the `select` dimensions rather wraps it inside a scrollable container