# Wicket Palette - Horizontal scrollbar is not shown in firefox

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, wicket

At the moment I'm using wicket for an application, I put an palette inside  html page. And everything is fine, but when I insert an option longher then the size of palette I lose half the option string. I solve in Chrome by modifying the following CSS tags

```
table.palette td.pane select {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    width: 100%;
}
```

html code:

```
<select class="choicesSelect" name="destinatari:choices" id="choices3f" multiple="multiple" size="20" onfocus="Wicket.Palette.choicesOnFocus('choices3f','selection40','recorder3e');" ondblclick="Wicket.Palette.add('choices3f','selection40','recorder3e');">
<option value="0000024174">null|null|null</option>
<option value="0000026648">null|null|null</option>
<option value="0000008473">ZWINA|ROMA | null</option>
</select>
```

[click here to see html code and css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4LVD.jpg)

but firefox does not seem to recognize these instructions.
how can i fix my problem? (I need to show a vertical and horizontal scrollbar).

Comment: instead of a screenshot, copy the code into stackverflow,

Comment: Please edit your question add more information . we have no idea what design issue

Comment: You'll have to put an "overflow: auto" on the containing div, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250724/select-box-html-horizontal-scroll

Comment: thank you for answer, i cant modify the html near select (java create html structure) i have only one div before select