# Scrollbar for size 0 dropdown list in html

Tags: javascript, css, html

Not able to get horizontal/vertical scrollbar for select drop down with size="0".
Ask: Need scrollbar if option item is too big.

```html
<select style="width:50px">
  <option value="">I am to big, I need Horizontal scrollbar</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think this post may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917824/how-to-get-horizontal-scroll-bar-in-select-box-in-ie

Comment: This may also be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250724/select-box-html-horizontal-scroll

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a horizontal scrollbar like this?

```css
.container {
  width: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <select>
    <option value="">I am to big, I need Horizontal scrollbar</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</div>
```