# How do you create a select element with a horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a select element that has a horizontal scrollbar. I tried setting the `overflow-x: scroll` property, but it does not work. Why won't this code generate a horizontal scrollbar?

**Update:** It works on Chrome, but not Safari or Firefox. Why is this? How can I get it working on Firefox and Safari?

```css
select {
      height: 378px;
      width: 260px;
      overflow-x: scroll;
    }
```

```html
<select multiple>
  <option>THIS IS A VERY LONG OPTION THIS IS A VERY LONG OPTION</option>
  <option>THIS IS A VERY LONG OPTION THIS IS A VERY LONG OPTION</option>
  <option>THIS IS A VERY LONG OPTION THIS IS A VERY LONG OPTION</option>
  <option>THIS IS A VERY LONG OPTION THIS IS A VERY LONG OPTION</option>
  <option>THIS IS A VERY LONG OPTION THIS IS A VERY LONG OPTION</option>
  <option>THIS IS A VERY LONG OPTION THIS IS A VERY LONG OPTION</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Works in Chrome for me

Comment: @j08691 Ah yes it works on Chrome for me too. But not Safari or Firefox. (I have Firefox ESR 52.1.0, an old version.)

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250724/select-box-html-horizontal-scroll and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28579095/why-there-is-no-horizontal-scrollbar-for-select-in-firefox

Comment: No one wants to click to open a drop-down and then scroll horizontal and try to read it. Very poor design and not surprising it isn't well supported. Maybe consider a more reasonable design choice.. the answer is that it will only work in Chrome with a native <select>.

Comment: @Jhawins What is so unreasonable about having a scrollbar? How else do you handle really long text?

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<select multiple>
  <option>THIS IS A VERY LONG OPTION THIS IS A VERY LONG OPTION</option>
  <option>THIS IS A VERY LONG OPTION THIS IS A VERY LONG OPTION</option>
  <option>THIS IS A VERY LONG OPTION THIS IS A VERY LONG OPTION</option>
  <option>THIS IS A VERY LONG OPTION THIS IS A VERY LONG OPTION</option>
  <option>THIS IS A VERY LONG OPTION THIS IS A VERY LONG OPTION</option>
  <option>THIS IS A VERY LONG OPTION THIS IS A VERY LONG OPTION</option>
</select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{ 
width:260px;
overflow-x: scroll
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vjangra/oux7ya8g

Hope it helps you

Comment: This works in Firefox (ESR 52.1.0) but not Safari. Ugh, why is this so browser-dependent? :(

Comment: Use a custom implementation of a drop-down that supports multi-line formatting. You shouldn't have giant single line text in a horizontal scroll because of how painful the user experience is..